# Tópicos da página de contato não traduzidos

Tags: bug, status-pronto, tradução, internacionalização

Na página ["Entre em contato conosco"](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/contact) os tópicos da lista de seleção não estão traduzidos.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: confirmed, on it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Isso estava escondido fundo nas classes do modelo (nós localizamos no nível das visões). A expectativa é que seja traduzido tão logo a próxima rodada de traduções ocorra.

---

Resposta original:

> This was hidden deep in the model classes (we localize on the view level). Expect it to be translated as soon as the next translation round-trip happens.